# GO env variable PATH got messed up

Tags: go, path, gopath, fyne

I am trying to install package using go with below command:

`go install fyne.io/fyne/v2/cmd/fyne@latest`

This is the same as what the instruction said but ideally it should return below message

`Users/name/go/bin/fyne`
But when I enter the command it has below issue

`fyne not found`

The package author told me You likely don’t have the GOBIN path added to your PATH variable. I suspect it is golang/go#39531 that comes back to bite you.

When I execute export in the command line:

`export`

I am getting the below Golang path:

`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin`

I thought the path above was messed up because I have done multiple times of installing and uninstalling with uninstalling using below commands

I've done uninstall via:

`$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go`

`$ sudo rm /etc/paths.d/go`

Althought I've tried to change via:

`vim ~/.zshrc`

Add a line

`export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin`

It's still not working.

What’s the best approach to resolve adding GOBIN to path?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin is messed up? It looks good. Just append ~/go/bin to it. You could also use this script: https://github.com/udhos/update-golang

Comment: Hi Everton, thanks for replying and I have updated my question and hope this helps you understand where my issue is thanks!

Comment: Oh I found out, so need to add GOBIN to the path by doing below in ~/.zshrc: in command line, do `vim ~/.zshrc` then add new line by pressing key O, then paste in `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/yourusername/go/bin/` then do `:wq` and reload cmd and reload vs code.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to add `GOBIN` to `PATH`, do:

```
PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOBIN)
```

Since `GOBIN` often is `~/go/bin`, you usually could get away with just:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/go/bin
```

You can add that command to `~/.zshrc` to make it persistent and then source it to execute it immediately:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

After that, if your shell remains unable to find `fyne`, check that current `PATH` content includes `GOBIN` with:

```
echo $PATH
```

If it doesn't, something went wrong when adding `GOBIN` to `PATH`.